# How to remove tr using jquery selector?

Tags: jquery

When I click `remove` button the data is removed but I can't remove the `tr` that is shown in table.

```
<tr>

<td>name</td>
<td><button id="removebutton" data-id="?">Remove</button></td>
</tr>
```

I want to select `tr` that is in the top and remove it from the ajax response.

I have tried:

```
$("#removebutton).on("click",function(){
  success: function(res){
  $(this).parents("tr").remove(); //this doesn't work
  }
});
```

Comment: what is success function come from it's inside ajax

Comment: @KrishnaJonnalagadda yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `arrow function` instead. This makes sure that the scope is kept to the click event rather than the `success()`

```
$("#removebutton").on("click", function() {
  .....
  success: (res) => {
    $(this).parent().remove(); 
  }
  ....
});
```

Comment: @Nidhin Joseph would you mind explaining me why arrow function worked? not with normal function?

Comment: @A4family because you clicked on the exact element. Try to remove two rows :D

Comment: @charlietfl he has an ajax inside. the success comes from that.

Comment: @A4family [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-exchangeable) can help you understand better with arrow functions and normal function.

Comment: Can also use `context` option of `$.ajax` with a regular function  ... `context:this`

Answer (score 0):

You can use either:

```
$(this).parent().remove();

// or

$(this).closest('tr').remove();
```

Let me know if it works :)

**EDIT**

I am looking forward to know why I got a negative vote :)

You cannot use the SAME ID on multiple rows..

```
<button class="removebutton" data-id="?">Remove</button>
```

then this `$("#removebutton).` should be `$(".removebutton").`

And you are missing closing `"` above in your selector.

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: @A4family if you have multiple rows you cannot use ID on it, it should either be a class, or add `onclick` attribute on the button itself

Comment: yes i have multiple rows

Comment: take a look at my edit then

Comment: Thank you for the response!! I used arrow function and it worked.

Comment: Yes, because you deleted just one row :) try on another. With ID it won't work. Still my answer above is straight to the non-working line..